# What is replacement of this function for converting order item to quote item

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento2.3.2, quoteitem

As magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart class is deprecated

```
/**
 * Shopping cart model
 *
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @deprecated 100.1.0 Use \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote instead
 * @see \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Cart extends DataObject implements CartInterface
```

But i dont see any equivalent function to add order item with qty to quote in **Magento\Quote\Model\Quote** to this function in cart class

```
/**
     * Convert order item to quote item
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem
     * @param true|null $qtyFlag if is null set product qty like in order
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addOrderItem($orderItem, $qtyFlag = null)
```

Please suggest an alternative approach to add old order item to quote .

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue. Let me know if you found anything